# How do i do token based authentication with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, authentication, alamofire

The server is written in node.js/express, will share the code below.

My goal is to authenticate a user into the ios application for example, let say the user is presented with the UI

[image]

On the IOS/Swift side, user enter the email and the password

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let parameters = [
            "email": emailField.text!,
            "password": passwordField.text!
        ]

        // What exactly I have to write to authenticate the user??
        Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://genietesting.herokuapp.com/auth/login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)


    }


}
```

if the user succeed then will redirect to a new screen with the user data, based on the token that have been given by the server.

node.js/express sample codes for login in

```
app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, '+password', function(err, user) {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid email and/or password' });
      }
      user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (!isMatch) {
          return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Invalid email and/or password' });
        }
        res.send({ token: createJWT(user)});
      });
    });
  });
```

What the code above will do is simply , find the user in the mongodb database, if it doesn't exist, simply send a 401 attached with a message, if found then compare the password if its correct or not, if it is correct then send the token back to the client.

I understand the server part, but on the IOS/Swift part what exactly I have to write to authenticate the user with the token given by the server?

Comment: would you set the answer as accepted if there wasn't any problems?

Answer (score 1):

basically you should check the response the server provides for your request. I think the following code will help:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://genietesting.herokuapp.com/auth/login", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseString { response in
         print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
         print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
         if let httpError = response.result.error {
             let statusCode = httpError.code
             // show the error message to user
         } else { //no errors
             let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
             // proceed to the next page
         }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to store the token in keychain or nsuserdefaults on the IOS part?

Comment: It really depends on what you're going to need the token for later. If you want the user to log in every time they open the app, you can store it in memory, but if you want to keep it for future uses, I suggest keeping it in the keychain and NOT the user defaults, for security reasons.

Comment: store it in memory? as in another database like redis or mongodb?

Comment: NO! I meant in a variable in RAM.